# Decorative, graphical horizontal separators in Libreoffice Writer v5

Tags: libreoffice

Using LibreOffice Writer 5.0.3.2, I'd like to create a decorative, graphical horizontal separator between sections of text. A [nearly duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/totally-sweet-horizontal-rules-in-latex/76547) in the TeX StackExchange gives this example:

[image: Lorem Ipsum with decorative lines between paragraphs]

... though unlike that example, I will use the *same* image every time.

I can get a plain horizontal line by typing `---` and letting AutoFormat set the "Horizontal Line" style, which uses borders to produce the line.  However I'd like to set a style that instead uses a single, elongated graphic.  (This is not the same as repeating tiny icon along a line.)

Extra points if LibreOffice comes with a set of graphics for this purpose, but otherwise I'm fine providing my own graphic.  My goal is to make this a reusable style where I don't have to "Insert > Image" and worry about anchoring and alignment every time I use this same element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new style (or Modify the existing "Horizontal Line" style).
2. On the **Area** tab of paragraph settings:

   - `Fill` = `Bitmap`
   - `Import Graphic...` to choose the image to use (you must provide your own).
   - Probably want to un-check `Tile` and `AutoFit`.
   - (The `Position`, `X-` and `Y-offset` boxes only apply to tiling, so are useless unless you checked `Tile`.)
3. On the **Font** tab, choose a tall enough font size to fit your entire decoration. We won't actually be typing text in this style though.
4. To avoid an endless stack of dividers, on the **Organizer** tab, set the "Next style" to that of the text you want to follow the divider.

Now when you want a divider, simply insert a new line in your document and set its style to this one.